# How to achieve Salting in HBase

Tags: hbase

I am trying to achieve salting in HBase. I have gone through the Apache ebook, and tried to execute some commands but i am still not clear how to implement it. For e.g. How am i suppose to create the table with salting enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table with a salted byte by specifying a table property “SALT_BUCKETS” with a value from 1 to 256. If you are using Phoenix, here is an example on how to do this:

CREATE TABLE table (a_key VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, a_col VARCHAR) SALT_BUCKETS = 20;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I had seen similar command on a webpage & had tried executing it, but not with much success. This morning i tried again, but the results were the same. Have you tried salting yourself ?